# jquery change border style from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to get this function working but have been unsuccessful. Also, there are no console errors.

```js
$("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
              });
    $("div").css('border-style' : str);
        })
        .change();
```

```css
.hiddentextarea{
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px #000; color: transparent; -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="testarea" >
            <div id="vss_border" class="vss_border" style="border-style: dotted; border-color: #8a4c8a; border-width:medium; align:center;">
     test
        </div>

<select  id="dropdown">
            <option value="dotted" selected="selected"> Normal : dotted box</option>
            <option value="dashed"> Normal : dashed box</option>
            <option value="solid">  Normal : solid box</option>
            <option value="double"> Normal : double box</option>
            <option value="groove">   3D   : groove box</option>
            <option value="ridge">    3D   : ridge box</option>
            <option value="inset">    3D   : inset box</option>
            <option value="outset">   3D   : outset box</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the `border` of an element when the value of the `select` element changes, you can do it with far more simple JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    $("div").css('border-style', this.value);
});
```

Note that using `"div"` as your selector in the change event handler will apply this to all `div` elements in the document.

Also note how the colon in your example has been replaced with a comma - the jQuery `css` function takes 2 parameters, which will be comma separated as would any parameters to a JavaScript function.

Comment: oh lol yes, kinda sad i didn't use my brain a bit further to get it solved, thank you ;)

Comment: Or even better, cut out the extra call I make like James here does it.

Comment: Personally, when debugging JavaScript, if something doesn't work I go through and add various calls to `console.log` in places of importance. I also use Firebug a lot. And jsfiddle.net is a great place to quickly and easily try out new ideas.

Comment: @James can you tell how to use console.log ?, thus in our situation firebug isn't showing anything

Comment: @SAFAD - Open Firebug, then open the Console tab, and try it with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/7fEPm/ You should see "Hello!" written to the console. This will also work with the developer tools in Chrome or IE9 (press F12 to open them). Alternatively, you can just use `alert` statements instead of `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Your css call needs a comma, not a colon. Additionally, it's easier to just grab the value using val():  http://jsfiddle.net/2wfVj/11/

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the <kbd>JS Lint</kbd> button (at the top of the screen) reveals:

```
Error:
Problem at line 6 character 33: Expected ')' and instead saw ':'.
$("div").css('border-style' : str);

Problem at line 6 character 34: Missing semicolon.
$("div").css('border-style' : str);

Problem at line 6 character 35: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
$("div").css('border-style' : str);

Problem at line 6 character 38: Missing semicolon.
$("div").css('border-style' : str);

Problem at line 6 character 38: Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
$("div").css('border-style' : str);

Problem at line 6 character 38: Stopping, unable to continue. (75% scanned).
Implied global: $ 1,3,4,6
```

Which are the faults identified by JS Fiddle.

All of these are fixed by switching the `:` to a `,` in the `css()` method: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2wfVj/9/).

Also: you were using `$(this).text()` instead of the `$(this).val()` (the `text()` method returned invalid CSS `normal : dotted box` for example, instead of just `dotted`).

That and the `+=` which appends the new value of the variable to the old value, rather than simply over-writing it. The fixed code (fixed so far as I can see) is:

```
$("select").change(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("select option:selected").each(function () {
                str = $(this).val();
              });
    $("div").css('border-style',str);
        })
        .change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2wfVj/13/).

And a slightly revised example:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var str = $("select option:selected").val();
    $("div").css('border-style', str);
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2wfVj/15/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $("#dropdown").change(onSelectChange);

});
function onSelectChange(){
    var selected = $("#dropdown option:selected");        
    var output = "";

    $("#testarea").css('border-style', selected.val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var getChoice = $("select option:selected").val();
    $('#vss_border').css('borderStyle', getChoice);
});
```

Here, on the change to the `dropdown`, you collect the selected option value.  Then adjust the css.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/2wfVj/12/